# How to move data between LVM LVs without physically rewriting it?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I want to move large volumes of data bewteen two LVM logical volumes (LVs) on the same physical volume. I use a SSD, so I don't want to write too much physically.

My understanding is that `cp`, `mv` and `rsync` will by default write the entire directory on the second LV, as opposed to just changing its path when moving it on the same partition.

How can I move, say, an entire directory between two logical volumes, without rewriting it entirely ?

Comment: It’s very easy: 1) Stop worrying about your SSD 2) ??? 3) Profit.

Comment: @DanielB I've thought about that. Just want to play it safe. If I can avoid writing hundreds of gigs, I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, there is no integration between the filesystem and the underlying LV. BTRFS has this, as does ZFS and APFS.

Comment: Maybe the stratis project will some time? It would definitely be a great selling point